# Changing computer's IP via PHP without resetting adsl modem (from localhost - xampp)

Tags: php, localhost, ip

First of all, i know, its a so crazy question. Please don't abuse on me. Im so sorry for taking your time. But, you know, there is no stupid question.

Question: Why i asked this crazy question?

Answer: Because, im using laptop (wireless connection), and i usually use my laptop in the kitchen or other rooms, and i must go to adsl modem to reset it whenever i need to change my ip. Every time i need to go to my room to reset my modem.

Well, i found a way to reset it by going to 192.168.2.2. however it is also taking my at least 3 minutes. So slow.

Today, i found a program: Router Reconnect 1.3 . This program shocked me, because it is getting new ip from my isp within the only 6 seconds without resetting my modem.

Well, You know, we love php :) Then, i asked myself, hey why can we do same job by using php on our localhosts?

Can we change our ip without resetting adsl modem by using php on our localhosts?

Note that: Im not talking about spoofing ip, using proxy. I just want to change my legal ip without resetting the modem within the only few seconds easily.

C'mon guys, lets discuss it.

Regards

Comment: Try using a tool like Wireshark to capture what Router Disconnect did (I guess that it's just a series of HTTP connections), then you can write a program that performs a same sequence of action to the router using cURL or `fsockopen`.

Comment: It seems to me that most of this question will be what does router reconnect do, which is more suited for superuser or perhaps serverfault.  Getting PHP to do it is another matter.  Most likely it'll be getting the router to reissue a DHCP request to the gateway, or just reconnecting to the RADIUS server.  Why do you need to change IP?

Comment: @Thai yes i agree. i though it. if we find a way, we can do it by using curl. it can be perfect :) anyway, thanks for comment. Im gonna test Wireshark right now.

Comment: @Orbling, i sometimes need to change my ip for so many reasons. rapidshare, paypal, forums etc... there are so many reasons. thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Andrew: I do not understand why your IP would need to change for any of those, unless you are acting in a malicious or subversive fashion.

Comment: @Orbling, C'mon mate, you know, we sometimes change our ip. for example: in the mirc, you need to change your ip when someone banned you. there are so many reasons. im not talking about spoofing ip, i just want to change my legal ip.

Comment: I enjoyed the emphasis on **Legal IP**, Wonders if the IP Address is actually *owned* by the ISP or the User?

Comment: @Andrew: When someone has banned you, yes you would need to change your IP, if you wished to subvert the ban. Same in general, the only sensible reasons why you would need to "change up" an IP address is if you had exhausted the use of the current one, ie. been banned; used up all your allocation on a service that uses the IP for limiting; trying to create multiple identities/accounts on something that would be traceable with a single IP. All malicious or subversive acts. The fact you quote PayPal in the list is very concerning indeed. I'm not judging you, just saying I can't see a just cause.

Comment: @Andrew: Also, "we sometimes change our IP" - I do not, as I have a static IP.  These "dynamic IPs" systems given out by ISPs are not supposed to be abused in that fashion.

Comment: whats your aim? fighting or helping? question is so clear. we are here to help. we are not on the court. i dont understand whats your aim? if you have a solution or something to say about question, yes you can say. you are talking about different issues.there is no stupid question. people ask questions and learn new things. get a life.

Comment: @RobertPitt, why don't you go to amusement park if you need to get enjoy? are you here for help or get enjoy and laugh? you guys are driving me crazy.

Comment: Andrew, Chill out mate, Life isn't just on the internet, if I find something amusing then that's my sense of humour, if i want to write it in a comment then that's my prerogative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this site that has URLs to access the reconnect feature on the router. It uses cURL from the command line, but you could perhaps use PHP's cURL extension as well... Though the command line is probably more streamlined, no point loading the PHP binary if the command line will do..

http://www.paehl.de/reconnect/

Comment: such a helpfull and great answer:) im checking that link right now. thanks for your kindly and helpfull answer. thanks again.